# Problem with reshaping dataset in NumPy in Python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm new to data analysis, so I'm trying to understand the code. But I have a problem with this code:

```
def univariate_data(dataset, start_index, end_index, history_size, target_size):
    data = []
    labels = []
    start_index = start_index + history_size
    if end_index is None:
        end_index = len(dataset) - target_size

    for i in range(start_index, end_index):
        indices = range(i-history_size, i)
        # Reshape data from (history_size,) to (history_size, 1)
        data.append(np.reshape(dataset[indices], (history_size, 1)))
        labels.append(dataset[i+target_size])
    return np.array(data), np.array(labels)
```

History_size is the size of the last time interval, target_size is an argument that determines how far into the future the model should learn to predict. In other words, target_size is the target vector to be predicted.
When I call this function like this:

```
univariate_past_history = 20
univariate_future_target = 0
TRAIN_SPLIT = 2000

x_train_uni, y_train_uni = univariate_data(uni_data, 0, TRAIN_SPLIT,
                                           univariate_past_history,
                                           univariate_future_target)
```

I have the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-148d84980a5b> in <module>()
      5 x_train_uni, y_train_uni = univariate_data(uni_data, 0, TRAIN_SPLIT,
      6                                            univariate_past_history,
----> 7                                            univariate_future_target)

<ipython-input-23-74f4c24fbf96> in univariate_data(dataset, start_index, end_index, history_size, target_size)
      9         indices = range(i-history_size, i)
     10         # Reshape data from (history_size,) to (history_size, 1)
---> 11         data.append(np.reshape(dataset[indices], (history_size, 1)))
     12         labels.append(dataset[i+target_size])
     13     return np.array(data), np.array(labels)

C:\Users\danil\.conda\envs\p35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1069         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
   1070         try:
-> 1071             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
   1072 
   1073             if not is_scalar(result):

C:\Users\danil\.conda\envs\p35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4728         k = self._convert_scalar_indexer(k, kind="getitem")
   4729         try:
-> 4730             return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
   4731         except KeyError as e1:
   4732             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: range(0, 20)
```

Can someone help with this part of the code?
How can I fix this error?

Comment: While the problem line has a `reshape` function, the traceback show that the error is in the pandas series indexing, which occurs before calling `reshape`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: make this change:

```py
for i in range(start_index, end_index):
    indices = pd.RangeIndex(i-history_size, i)
```

The error is in the expression `dataset[indices]`. `indices` is a `range` object; the error is telling you that `range(0, 20)` is not a valid key for `dataset[key]`.

Based on the traceback, it looks like `dataset` is a `pandas.Series` object. `Series` objects can accept sequences of indices as keys and return a Series consisting of the entries at the specified indices.

In Python, `range` objects are not sequences but simply iterable objects that contain the start, stop, and step values of the defined range. Thus, on their own they are not, strictly speaking, valid keys for a `Series`. Instead, you will want a Pandas `RangeIndex`. They, like Python `range` objects, only contain the start, stop, and step values, not every value in the range, so they save memory versus expanding the `range` into a `list` or a Pandas `Int64Index`. However, Pandas knows how to use them to index into a `Series`.

I'm not sure what version of Pandas you're running, but in current versions, Pandas will accept Python `range` objects as keys for a `Series`, probably by internally casting them into `RangeIndex` objects. I haven't looked into However, in older versions, trying to use a `range` object as a key for a Pandas `Series` will result in the error you ran into.

You can cast `indices` into Pandas `Index` (Pandas will automatically cast it into a `RangeIndex`):

```py
for i in range(start_index, end_index):
    indices = pd.Index(range(i-history_size, i))
```

Or, more simply, you can just create a `RangeIndex` directly:

```py
for i in range(start_index, end_index):
    indices = pd.RangeIndex(i-history_size, i)
```